# Qt : Placing an image inside a cicular Qlabel - Masking Concept?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been googling a lot on this topic and for some reason I think I am not setting the masks right. What I want to do is to display an image inside a QLabel that has circular shape.
Parts of the image that cross the boundary should not be displayed. This is what I am doing

```
QPixmap circ( ":/qt/images/circ.png" );
QPixmap img( ":/qt/images/no.bmp" );
ui.label_h->setMask(circ.mask());
ui.label_h->setPixmap(img);
```

the circ file is a png image with a circle that has black fill in it and img is apparently an image any suggestion on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated. My code apparently just shows the image in a square boundary

Update

This is what I am using

```
QPixmap circ( ":/qt/images/circ.png" );
    QPixmap mask = circ.createMaskFromColor(Qt::black, Qt::MaskOutColor);
    QPixmap img( ":/qt/images/no.bmp" );
    ui.label_h->setMask(mask);
    ui.label_h->setPixmap(img);
```

and this is the before after result

[image]

These are the links

http://i.tinyuploads.com/EFxSB7.png

http://i.tinyuploads.com/9knGNd.bmp

Answer (score 0):

You're calling circ.mask() which, according to the Qt docs: -

> Extracts a bitmap mask from the pixmap's alpha channel.

You said the circ image has a black circle, so either change it to have an alpha channel with the circle or create the mask from the image: -

```
QPixmap mask = circ.createMaskFromColor(Qt::black, Qt::MaskOutColor);
```

Then use this mask: -

```
ui.label_h->setMask(mask);
```

Comment: Are the source image and mask image the same size and colour depth and can you show the circ.png image too?

Comment: The links are in the post

Comment: As the two images are of different sizes, the mask isn't aligned. Reduce the size of the circle image to match that of your source image.